# how to extract hidden reviews from the website using python beautifulsoup?

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to extract all the review details like name, date, and reviewed data etc, for the below website of the product blueair.
https://www.costco.com/blueair-healthprotect-7410i-hepasilent-ultra-air-purifier-with-germshield.product.100750915.html
looks like it's hidden and used javascript.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests_html import HTMLSession

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) '\
           'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '\
           'Chrome/75.0.3770.80 Safari/537.36'}
URL = 'https://www.costco.com/blueair-healthprotect-7410i-hepasilent-ultra-air-purifier-with-germshield.product.100750915.html'
httpx = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
# print(httpx.text)
soup = BeautifulSoup(httpx.content,'html.parser')
for data in soup.findAll('span', class_='bv-content-datetime-stamp'):
    print(data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User the API with limit to fetch all the reviews

```py
import requests
import json

limit = 100
r = requests.get(f'https://api.bazaarvoice.com/data/batch.json?passkey=bai25xto36hkl5erybga10t99&apiversion=5.5&displaycode=2070_2_0-en_us&resource.q0=reviews&filter.q0=isratingsonly%3Aeq%3Afalse&filter.q0=productid%3Aeq%3A100750915&filter.q0=contentlocale%3Aeq%3Aen_CA%2Cen_US&sort.q0=relevancy%3Aa1&stats.q0=reviews&filteredstats.q0=reviews&include.q0=authors%2Cproducts%2Ccomments&filter_reviews.q0=contentlocale%3Aeq%3Aen_CA%2Cen_US&filter_reviewcomments.q0=contentlocale%3Aeq%3Aen_CA%2Cen_US&filter_comments.q0=contentlocale%3Aeq%3Aen_CA%2Cen_US&limit.q0={limit}&offset.q0=8&limit_comments.q0=3&callback=bv_351_53884')

comments = json.loads(r.text[13:-1])['BatchedResults']['q0']['Results']

print(comments[0]['ReviewText'])
```

```
This was a great purchase, beautifully packed, easy set-up, great app, sleek design, and very quiet.  The color bar shows the air quality being processed by the unit.

While I signed up for the auto-ship subscription service based on the Bluair statement that the app will analyze the filter condition and send a new filter right when it's needed.  However, after speaking with two Bluair employees, it seems that rather sending a new filter when needed, Bluair just sends a new filter every six months regardless of filter condition and use -- certainly not high tech!
```

These are the query parameters you can tune

```
passkey: bai25xto36hkl5erybga10t99
apiversion: 5.5
displaycode: 2070_2_0-en_us
resource.q0: reviews
filter.q0: isratingsonly:eq:false
filter.q0: productid:eq:100750915
filter.q0: contentlocale:eq:en_CA,en_US
sort.q0: relevancy:a1
stats.q0: reviews
filteredstats.q0: reviews
include.q0: authors,products,comments
filter_reviews.q0: contentlocale:eq:en_CA,en_US
filter_reviewcomments.q0: contentlocale:eq:en_CA,en_US
filter_comments.q0: contentlocale:eq:en_CA,en_US
limit.q0: 30
offset.q0: 38
limit_comments.q0: 3
callback: bv_351_54703
```

Comment: change the limit to 366, I just put as an example.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a static web page, so what you have to do is to analyze the request and response. Here is an simplified approach to your case.

- Supposed you are using Chrome, press `F12` to open your devtools, turn to the tab named `Network`, and refresh the page.
- Click `Network` again and press `<C-f>` to open search pane, type in one of the reviews like "I purchased a Blueair", press `<Enter>`.
- Then you can catch `batch.json` in the result, check it out and you will know where you can get the data you want.

[image: No]

What you can do next is analyzing the request URL and parameters of the api, and try sending your request to that. If everything goes right, you should be able to get the same `batch.json`.